# How to read a local JSON file in React JS + Typescript app and access the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, office-addins

I am trying to read a local JSON file in ReactJS + Typescript office add-in app.
I created a `typings.d.ts` in the `src` folder and added the following.

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
declare module "json!*" {
    let json: any;
    export default json;
}
```

I imported the file in my component file like this

```
import * as data from './../../mock-data/pre-output.json';
```

The JSON file has data similar to the following

```
{
 "result": {
     "ruleFeedback": [
         {
             "key": "Deal Size",
             "version": 1,
             "category": "Segmentation"
         }
      ]}
 }
```

And I tried to access this `data` like the following in my function.

```
const newData = data.results.ruleFeedback.map(item =>
                [item.key, item.version,item.category, item.selectedValue]);
```

But I am getting an error **`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.results.ruleFeedback')`**

I even tried the `import` like this

```
import data = require('./../../mock-data/pre-output.json');
```

But I am getting the same error.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

I am very new to this JS technology stack.

Comment: As preoutput is not defined that's why you are getting error preoutput is of undefined. Try using **data** instead of **preoutput**

Comment: @ShivamMuttoo I have edited my question. I missed changing the variable name in that line while writing the question. I was using `data` itself.

Comment: try `const data = require('./../../mock-data/pre-output.json');`

Comment: You might have to parse the json from the file. Using ``import * as data from './../../mock-data/pre-output.json';`` to get your data should be fine. Can you try to parse your data and save it in a new variable? Like the following: ``let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);``

Comment: @Bobvan'tPadje I did try that, then I get the typescript error `[ts] Argument of type 'typeof import("*.json")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem loading JSON data once. For me, the solution was to put the json file into the public folder of my app (generated with create-react-app)

Comment: I did try that as well. Even though I started with `create-react-app`, the office add-in scaffolding is generated through [Yeoman Office Add-ins generator] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-get-started-react). So the webpack builds the output to `dist' folder.